# How to change second y-axis text font size in pentaho ccc charts

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

[image]How to change second y-axis text font-size in pentaho chart

I putted some  text (i.e Monthly Cost ($000) in orthoAxisTitle  it shows fine. How to put some text in second y-axis also[image]

Comment: Sir, How did you color the single line  with multiple color ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to define **ortho2 axis title**, put your text to `ortho2AxisTitle` parameter and its font definition to `ortho2AxisTitleFont` parameter:

- **ortho2AxisTitle:** `Your title`
- **ortho2AxisTitleFont:** `10px sans-serif`

If you want to adjust font of **ortho2 axis label**, define the font using `extensionPoints` parameter:

- **extensionPoints:** `[["ortho2AxisLabel_font", "normal 17px "Open Sans"'"]]`

[image]

You can define the font also for all axes by setting `axisLabel_font` extension point. And then play with the rest of axes by e.g. setting text angle:

- **extensionPoints:** `[["axisLabel_font", "normal 17px "Open Sans"'"], ["ortho2AxisLabel_textAngle", "-0.6"]]`

Comment: Thank for replay. I tried but still it's not working.

Comment: Do you to adjust a font of the ortho2 axis title? Or ortho2 axis label font?

Comment: I have extended my answer.

Comment: axisLabel_font is working fine. But ortho2AxisLabel_font extension point is not working why? I am using pentatho bi server 5.2.

Comment: I use the same version 5.2 and it works for me. Could you send the value of extensionPoints parameter you set up?

Comment: I added that extension image in above please check it. i tried so many times still it's not working

Comment: `y2AxisLabel_font` should also work. But it is strange that it doesn't work for you. Maybe try to keep one extension point to test it. What version of CGG do you use?

Comment: y2AxisLabel_font also not working. This is the CGG version 5.2.0.0-209

Comment: How to add ortho2Axistitle also.anyway ortho2Axistitle is not working in my system is there any solution to add ortho2Axistitle as above i discussed.

Comment: The `ortho2AxisTitle` can be added to the `chartDefinition` in chart's `Advanced Properties` CDE menu (not an extension point). *Note that `plot2` parameter must be set to true.*

Comment: By the way I use exactly the same version of *Pentaho ctools* you use.

Comment: It's already plot2 setted to true only.if you add some text to  ortho2Axistitle proporties its not showing. if i do anything on ortho2 proporties is not working.can you give me better solution for these.

Comment: No, nothing more comes into my mind. I would try to reinstall ctools or try it on Pentaho 5.3 instead..

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much for your answers. Sorry for my english.

Comment: I noticed you voted up and later removed it :). if you find my answer useful or my comments helped you, you can vote up for an answer. :)

Comment: Sorry for that, I fully satisfied your answers. I voted your answers. Thank you..